# PHP & AJAX Request 500(Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to update my database per record with a AJAX Request. The problem is that it gives me a 500 error when i submit the edit. The update 'RecordData' gives me all the data but that is it.

My Update file.

```
    $data = $_POST['recordData'];
    str_parse($data, $data);

    echo   "Record Id is: " . $data[0];
    echo $query = "UPDATE bier 
              SET naam = '$data['naam'], brouwer = '$data['brouwer']', type = '$data['type']', gisting = '$data['gisting']', perc = '$data['perc']', inkoop_prijs = '$data['inkoop_prijs']'
              WHERE id= '".$data['id']."'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

echo $_POST['recordId'];
```

My AJAX Function

```
function editRecord(data){
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        database: 'updateRecords',
        recordData: data.serialize()
    },
    url: "actions/update.php",
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        ModalClose();
    }
});
}
```

And my Form:

```
        <form id="FormBier" action="#" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Naam</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="naam"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brouwer</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="brouwer"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="type"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gisting</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="gisting"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Percentage</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="perc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Inkoop Prijs</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="inkoop_prijs"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="submit" onclick="editRecord($('#FormBier'))" value="bewerk">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: 500 - check your logs

Comment: What is `str_parse`? Did you mean to use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), if so then you are getting the 500 because its trying to use a function, `str_parse`, that doesn't exist, and because you havent quoted your query properly. As Fred -ii- points out you need to check your servers error logs

Comment: as stated by @PatrickEvans error reporting would have thrown you something about an undefined function.

Comment: I fixed the error 500, the problem was in the connection, but it doesn't update my data and I cant find a error so I have no clue where I have to search for the problem.

Comment: So I found out that I have a problem in my query, but I don't know what I do wrong. I tried several things.

Answer (score 0):

check POST and variable using isset and  change query as mention below code.

```
   echo $query = 'UPDATE bier SET naam = '.$data["naam"].', brouwer = '.$data["brouwer"].', type = '.$data["type"].', gisting = '.$data["gisting"].', perc = '.$data["perc"].', inkoop_prijs = '.$data["inkoop_prijs"].' WHERE id= '.$data["id"];
```

Comment: The problem is not in the query, but it doesn't use the text I filled in into the input fields.

Comment: try this and check input with variables .print_r($_POST);